# In the US, will closing a bank account negatively affect your credit score?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, bank-account

In the US, will closing a bank account negatively affect your credit score? I've had it with my bank and I'm thinking of moving my money to a smaller Credit Union. Would this affect my credit score? The current account is the one I've had open the longest. I would close both a checking/savings account and re-open them with a local CU.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: FICO Score]

FICO score tracks credit, not checking or savings. Unless there was a credit line attached, no impact at all.

Comment: There are agencies that track checking accounts, but generally they only track accounts that were closed for fraud or account abuse.

Answer (score 5):

Not at all, no effect whatsoever.